# How to export next version of apk from Unity 4.6?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, apk

I have published my first android game today. 
But it had a bug which I have fixed. But now I dont know how to export next version of apk from unity. 
I updated bundle version to 1.1, but Google rejected it saying it's a version 1.
I am trying different things.

Comment: What *exactly* is the error message, and where have you changed the version from 1.0 to 1.1?

Comment: thanx for the reply , i changed the Bundle Version Code and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

In Unity, if you go Edit > Project Settings > Player, and select the tab for your Android settings, under Other Settings, you need to change both the Bundle Version *and* the Bundle Version Code.

If your Bundle Version Code says 1, try making it say 1.1 or maybe 2.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I was changing only Bundle Version not the Bundle Version Code. that was the problem